# Как применить стиль к блоку с динамическим классом?

Tags: css

```
<div id="hook_Block_FourthCol">    //id постоянный
  <div class="dynamic">            //Как скрыть этот блок?
   <div class="dynamic"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dynamic">            //Этот должен остаться виден
   <div class="dynamic"></div>
  </div>

  div#hook_Block_FourthCol div {   //Скрывает все последующие div ((
  display: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо писать вот такой селектор   `#hook_Block_FourthCol > div:nth-child(1)`

Знак > означает, что будут выбираться дочерние элементы div относительно родителя, т.е. #hook_Block_FourthCol. Ну и nth-child(1) - выбираем первого потомка